# How do I parse through an array of IDs to return all the corresponding records in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

let me clarify:

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.assembly_part (
        assembly_id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        assembly_name VARCHAR(300),
        part_id_array INTEGER[]);
```

The idea here is that `part_id_array` will be records with different length arrays of integers,

eg.

```
{1,2,3}
{4,5}
{6,7,8,9}
```

And here I have the corresponding subassembly table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.subassembly_part (
        part_id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        part_name VARCHAR(300),
        part_rev VARCHAR(300),
        part_mat_req_id INTEGER);
```

So for array `{1,2,3}` I would want to return the rows from subassembly table where part_id is 1,2,3 respectively. How would the select statement look? Please let me know if I can be more clear, thank you!

EDIT:

Tried the following but didn't work out

```
SELECT *
FROM public.subassembly_part
WHERE public.subassembly_part.part_id = ANY (public.assembly_part.part_id_array);
```

Got this error:

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "subassembly_part"
```

Comment: `WHERE part_id = ANY (part_id_array)` See [ARRAY ANY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.30.16)

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I tried your approach but didn't really work out, added it to the OP

Comment: My mistake, in my original comment I forgot to add `()`. So it should be: `... WHERE public.subassembly_part.part_id = ANY (public.assembly_part.part_id_array);`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I'm getting a different error now, updated the OP, do you know why? Thank you

Comment: Your approach works with joins, but I was wondering if there's a way to return results without doing so (similarly to how I tried to in the OP)

Comment: Maybe you want string_agg and group by to construct your array?

Comment: I'm not believing that query got that error. I could see: `ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "assembly_part"` happening. In any case you will need to join the tables to use fields from them both.

Comment: Now if you just want to select from `subassembly_part` all those parts that have `part_id` in a hard coded id array, then you can do: `select * from  subassembly_part where subassembly_part.part_id= any ('{1, 2, 3}');`. Or simpler yet: `select * from  subassembly_part where subassembly_part.part_id in (1, 2, 3);` . This will only get you information from `subassembly_part` to get the corresponding `assembly_part` will require a join.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver if i could select a comment as best answer I would, this solved my question, thanks!

Comment: Created an answer that includes the queries from my  previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to just select parts from `subassembly_part` that match an array of `part_id`'s then:

```
select * from  subassembly_part where subassembly_part.part_id= any ('{1, 2, 3}');
```

This can be simplified by not using an array and doing:

```
select * from  subassembly_part where subassembly_part.part_id in (1, 2, 3);
```